# Application.UserName modifies the number format

Tags: date, excel, vba

I have a cell in an Excel file that I want to populate with the current date&time and the user name. The cell is populated by clicking a button.

Until now I was not using the function `Application.UserName` and the date & time output was formatted correctly (e.g: `07.01.2014 16:57`)

After I have added the `& Space(1) & Application.UserName` piece of coding the formatting of date & time is not formatted the way I want (depending on the user that populates the cell I get results like: `09-Jan-14 11:30:13 + USERNAME` or `1/7/2014 5:59:43 PM + USERNAME`)

I guess that it takes the formatting from the user's regional settings, correct ?

My question is how can I override those settings as it looks that the `ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm"` piece of code is no longer working good.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveCell = Now() & Space(1) & Application.UserName
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Date/Time NumberFormat will only work if the cell has a valid Date/Time. So the trick is to change the format first and then add the username.

Is this what you are trying?

```
With ActiveCell
    .Value = Now()
    .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm"
    .Value = .Text & Space(1) & Application.UserName
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, That solved my problem. I'm a newbie with the VBA coding, but trying to learn step by step. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3013587: Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Wow, congratulations on the 50k! :)

Comment: @BK201: Thanky Thanky :)